# Use php to trigger another php script, then ignore

Tags: php, process, background-process

What I'm trying to work out how to do is this: I've got a php file let's call `trigger.php` that runs some php code that sets off another php file we'll call `backgroundProcess.php` to start processing.

Although `trigger.php` needs to ignore what happens to `backgroundProcess.php`, it just has to start it processing and it will stop while `backgroundProcess.php` keeps going.

**edit1**

I'm running this on Windows Wampserver 2.1 So this has to be a windows command.

**edit2**

Solved it with the following command, thanks to jakenoble's suggestions:

```
exec("C:\wamp\bin\php\phpVERSION_NUMBER\php.exe -f C:\wamp\www\path\to\backgroundProcess.php");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `exec()` and add an `&` to the end of the call, plus an output stream:

In trigger.php

```
exec("php backgroundProcess.php > /dev/null &");
```

You can find out more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm using WAMPSERVER 2.1 so perhaps that's the issue? Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Unless I'm doing something else wrong.... I've got both php files in the same folder and am running the the above command.

Comment: It won't work, Windows probably doesn't know where `php` is installed and therefore cannot execute it. Try launching a command window and executing the script there, then take that code and use it in `exec()`. I don't use Windows so can't really help much more. You might want to revise your question as this changes everything.

Comment: Solved! :) With the following command: `exec("C:\wamp\bin\php\phpVERSION_NUMBER\php.exe -f C:\wamp\www\path\to\backgroundProcess.php");`

Comment: Unix or windows alike, this assumes the php location to be in the PATH variable (`%PATH%` for Windows and `$PATH` for unix). In unix it generally is, while in Windows it generally isn't. The alternative to adding the php directory to the path environment variable is inserting a full path. This is possible in windows and unix, but it won't be portable at all.

Comment: This will not work on shared hosting accounts, such as GoDaddy.