# Execute .bat file, without waiting for end

Tags: php, windows, apache, exec

I am trying to make a kind of panel where I would like to have "start/stop" operations of application(Game server).

HTTP server is running on Windows Server 2008 R2(WAMP SERVER 64-bit)

I found out that I can use: psExec, it isn't waiting for finish application, and at least providing me PID.

There is a code of .bat:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\LucasArts\Star Wars Jedi Knight Jedi Academy\GameData\"
.\jampded  +set dedicated 2 +set net_port 29075 +set fs_game lugormod +exec server.cfg
```

and the PHP code:

```
<?php
$command = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LucasArts\\Star Wars Jedi Knight Jedi Academy\\GameData\\PsExec.exe\" -d \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LucasArts\\Star Wars Jedi Knight Jedi Academy\\GameData\\serverstart.bat\"";
//echo ($command);
exec("$command");
?>
```

showing: error while executing test.php, execution was longer than 30s

But when I am writing that command in console, it's showing PID, and exiting automatically, even when started prog is still being run.

(sorry for my English ;) )

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP exec() as Background Process (Windows Wampserver Environment)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367261/php-exec-as-background-process-windows-wampserver-environment)

Comment: Fyi, `"$command"` makes no sense. It is identical to `$command`

Comment: Related, [How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/835941)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PsExec should be enough to run process in background, however it requires user to accept EULA first (interactive window). If you are running it from command line, you had already accepted the terms, but apache (and php under apache) runs as system user that have not accepted the terms yet.

You can try running psexec with `/accepteula` option and see if it helps.

[+]
To get PID on output:

```
echo exec('psexec.exe -accepteula -i -d "c:/file.bat" 2>&1')
```

Comment: Because psexec writes pid to STDERR and system user does not have active session running, so you need to add `-i` to psexec arguments and redirect STDERR to STDOUT: `echo exec('psexec.exe -accepteula -i -d "c:/file.bat" 2>&1')`

Comment: Ok, the showed PID is of CMD.exe, and I need PID of jampded.exe(application which start from bat file), is there a way?

Comment: Either run the code without bat file or use `tasklist` with filters to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$command = "Path_to_your_bat_file";
pclose(popen("start /B ". $command, "r"));
```

It is working for me..

Comment: It will only work if you don't need to keep the process running