# Is it possible to get the PID of a process launched by exec() in Windows XP?

Tags: php, windows, exec

I am using the `exec()` function to execute the same external programs, and I want to stop one of them in some case. But the following command:

```
taskkill /IM program.exe
```

will get all `program.exe` killed. So the best way I thought was to kill program process by its PID.

So,I thought the way was to get the PID every time the program was executed, and then kill it.

I am using PHP 5.3 on Windows XP.

Comment: You can find out about PIDs under windows using the `tasklist` command. I can not provide a demo because taskkill and tasklist are broken on my computer and I have no clue how to fix them.

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348572/execute-bat-file-without-waiting-for-end/9348938#9348938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exec on Windows hangs until child process is over. You need PID of a child, so I suppose you want to nohup a child.

Try this code, it worked for me. It nohups notepad.exe and displays its PID

```
    $command = 'notepad.exe';
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->exec("notepad.exe");
print_r ( $oExec->ProcessID )
```

pay attention to $WshShell->exec and not $WshShell->run as some googled ressources claim.

May it help someone else

Answer (score 0):

The PID should be returned as the first element of the `$output` array.

```
exec($command, $output);
$pid = (int)$output[0];
```

Comment: I am running your code and get any PID result,it just lunch the cmd.exe and program.exe [the external program I used]....

Comment: @qinHaiXiang If you launch `cmd.exe` and use it to launch `program.exe`, then of course you will get the PID from `cmd.exe`, which is pretty useless. Why don't you launch `program.exe` directly?

Comment: I am using fastcopy[ the command line mode ] to copy files in background.My command is:"'fastcopy.exe .....';",the exec() auto launch the cmd.exe and then fastcopy.exe.....