# How can I force a PHP script to continue on with a script after calling exec()?

Tags: php, exec

I'm using the `exec` function in PHP to run a command. The command I'm running can often take quite a bit of time and I don't have any need to read it's output. Is there a simple way of telling PHP not to wait for the `exec` command to finish before moving on with the rest of the script?

Comment: do it as a separate process perhaps?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do I just append `&` to the end of the command?

Comment: `exec("nohup $your_command &")` - run command immune to hangups, output to non-tty (`nohup`), run it in background (`&`)

Comment: @Nemoden: Awesome! Thanks. So each time I call that it will start a new process, correct? Is there a similar way to run these on separate threads?

Comment: yes, new process will start, I'll  demonstrate it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// nohup_test.php:

// a very long running process
$command = 'tail -f /dev/null';
exec("nohup $command >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &"); // here we go
printf('run command: %s'.PHP_EOL, $command);
echo 'Continuing to execute the rest of this script instructions'.PHP_EOL;

for ($x=1000000;$x-->0;) {
  for ($y=1000000;$y-->0;) {
    //this is so long, so I can do ps auwx | grep php while it's running and see whether $command run in separate process
  }
}
```

run nohup_test.php:

```
$ php nohup_test.php
run command: tail -f /dev/null
Continuing to execute the rest of this script instructions
```

Let's find out pids of our processes:

```
$ ps auwx | grep tail
nemoden   3397  0.0  0.0   3252   636 pts/8    S+   18:41   0:00 tail -f /dev/null
$ ps auwx | grep php
nemoden   3394 82.0  0.2  31208  6804 pts/8    R+   18:41   0:04 php nohup_test.php
```

as you can see, pid is different and my script is running without waiting for `tail -f /dev/null`.

Comment: Using `/dev/null` was key to getting this working correctly. For some reason when I specified an actual log file location (i.e. `/path/to/logfile` as suggested by @zaf), PHP still waited for the process to finish. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: if you specify a log file like so: `exec("nohup $command >/tmp/my.log 2>/dev/null &");` and you run `php nohup_test.php` it doesn't print `Continuing to execute the rest of this script instructions` ? Because it works just fine or... should work so... It's really odd otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use (you can use exec or system instead of paasthru):

```
passthru("/path/to/program args >> /path/to/logfile 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too familiar with some of the syntax here, though. What does the `>>` and `2>&1 &` do?

Comment: >> will send the output of the program to the log file. The '2>&1' will redirect error messages to the standard output, basically meaning  all output will go to the log file. The '&' means run the command in the background.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called an Asynchronous call, like answered here:

[Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

[php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process#45966)

[PHP exec() as Background Process (Windows Wampserver Environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367261/php-exec-as-background-process-windows-wampserver-environment)

Comment: Thanks! I searched quite a bit for this before posting but apparently never used the right keywords...