# background process in php using shell_exec()

Tags: php, exec, wamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP exec() as Background Process (Windows Wampserver Environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367261/php-exec-as-background-process-windows-wampserver-environment)

I am using WAMP server to execute my php scripts.

I have a controller file called `MainController.php` to which a command line argument is passed. On the basis of command line argument a new separate php script `e.g. test1.php , test2.php and so on` is executed using `exec()` function every time.

I want that my `MainController.php` should not wait for the response from the executed php script `like test1.php` and should proceed further.

Currently I am using following statement to execute the script in background
`shell_exec('C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe test1.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');`

but it giving me an error

`The system cannot find the path specified.`

Kindly suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The commands you are using works on *nix systems, not on windows.

Comment: @SalmanA..ohk..I was not aware of that.. thanks for the appropriate link