# PHP - start a minecraft_server.jar in background on Windows

Tags: php, minecraft

I'm doing an administration for my server and I want to make it remotelly but I found a problem. When I'm starting minecraft server, the process of that file is still working and my page is going to be frozen till that process is killed.

I found many of answers but unfortunately, I'm running it on Windows.

Is it possible? I know that I can start the .bat server which start server, but I want to make it clear.

My code:

```
chdir("D:/xampp/htdocs/hosting/servers/" . $id);
                //$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
                //$oExec = $WshShell->Run("ava -Xmx1g -jar minecraft_server.jar", 0, false);
//idk how WshShell works, but it didn't worked..
                exec("java -Xmx1g -jar minecraft_server.jar");
```

**Thank you in advance for your reply!**

**EDIT**

Well, got one problem. I've tried to start something else with WinShell but nothing happend. Nothing is happening when I want to start with WinShell so do I have to enable something to enable WinShell or do anybody know why my WinShell running nothing?

Code

```
chdir("D:/xampp/htdocs/hosting/servers/" . $id);
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("java -Xmx1g -jar minecraft_server.jar", 0, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have solution.
Even Wscript.Shell won't work, this command is working.

```
$cmd = "java -jar D:/xampp/htdocs/hosting/servers/" . $id . "/minecraft_server.jar";
pclose(popen("CMD /C start /B " . $cmd, "r"));
```

**Thank you for trying to help!**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to trigger the Minecraft server as a background process. While I haven't been able to try the solution below myself, this thread sounds like it's trying to solve a similar problem:

[PHP exec() as Background Process (Windows Wampserver Environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5367261/8507437)

Comment: Yea, but as I told I was trying it.


                    chdir("D:/xampp/htdocs/hosting/servers/" . $id);
                    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
                    $oExec = $WshShell->Run("java -Xmx1G -jar minecraft_server.jar", 0, false);

Comment: Unfortunately, it do anything even if I am starting some exe files.
Do I have to enable something?
I am using xampp.